# How use the same method for different classes as parameter

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I've got a function with List<> set as the parameter, which looks something like this:

```
private Double CalculateConsumption(List<GasConsumRecord> gasRecord)
{
  ...
  foreach (var record in gasRecords){
    var x = record.Counter;
    var y = record.Pressure;
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

*GasConsumRecord* class has more properties but in this function I use only 2.

And I've got another class - *AirConsumRecord* which has the same 2 properties but other properties are different. Both classes have only properties, but no methods.

My question is: How can I use the same method for two different class List<> as parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try using a generic method, which is analogous to a template in c++:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need your classes to implement the same interface, or derive from the same base class, which contains these two properties, then use a generic method with a type constraint:

If you use interfaces:

```
public interface IRecord {
    int Counter { get; set; }
    int Pressure { get; set; }
}

public class GasConsumRecord : IRecord {
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public int Pressure { get; set; }
}

public class AirConsumRecord : IRecord {
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    public int Pressure { get; set; }
}

private Double CalculateConsumption<T>(List<T> records)
    where T : IRecord
{
    foreach (IRecord record in records){
        var x = record.Counter;
        var y = record.Pressure;
    }
}
```

Comment: Records parameter can be directly of type List<IRecord>

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: only if the original object is in fact of the type `List<IRecord>`. Otherwise, it must be done as a constrained generic, as Joe shows here. If you could in fact pass an instance of `List<GasConsumRecord>` to a method that expects an instance of `List<IRecord>`, then that method could add an element of `AirConsumRecord` to the list. Obviously that won't/shouldn't work.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri does bring up a good point that you you can make your parameter `IList<IRecord>` or `IEnumerable<IRecord>` rather than `List<T>`, if those interfaces are good enough for the purposes of the implementation. There are a bunch of things you can do with [covariance and contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) which I don't entirely understand, but it definitely would work here.

Comment: @JoeEnos: this is IT! Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. I tried before Giorgi's idea, but it didn't work. Once more - Thanks!